# Call method once every 5 minutes

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I want to send 1 mail every 5 minutes irrepective of how many times i call sendmail() in 5 minutes ?
For eg.

- if i call sendmail at 10 pm .first mail should be sent
- If i call sendmail at 10:03 and 10:04 no mail should be sent.
- If  i call sendmail at 10 :06 mail should be sent as difference is
  greater than 5 mins

How to achieve it?

```
public class SendMyEmail {
 private boolean sendMail=false;
 public void sendmail(String msg) {
 if(sendMail) {
 System.out.println(" Mail sent " +msg);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply create a timestamp when your class is instantiated (in the constructor).

Your send method simply checks "more than 5 minutes since that timestamp"?

If yes: then take a new timestamp, and send the mail.

If no: do nothing.

That's all you will need. Not going to provide code here, as this is probably homework, and the point is that *you* learn how to write the corresponding code.

Answer (score 2):

Have a variable in your SendMyEmail class that stores the time when you call your function. Then simply add your logic to an if condition that checks if it has been 5 minutes since the method was called.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create what we call a `Schedule` - a procedure that runs consistently and periodically. Your Schedule would have the following logic:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *") // Will run every minute
public synchronized void sendEmailSchedule() {

    Email email = getEmail();

    Date lastTimeSent = email.getLastTimeEmailWasSent();
    Date now = new Date();
    
    long difference = now.getTime() - lastTimeSent.getTime();
    long differenceInMinutes = difference / (60 * 1000) % 60; 
    
    if (differenceInMinutes > 5) {
        sendEmail(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP says that they can arbitrarily call the method at any time, thus the class itself needs to be aware of when the method was last called.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is almost what you need.
The cron expression means, trigger every 5 minutes: on Minute 0, 5, 10, etc.

```
public class SendMyEmail
{
    private volatile String mailMessage;

    public void sendmail(String msg)
    {
        mailMessage = msg;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * *")
    public void sendmailJob()
    {
        if (mailMessage != null)
        {
            System.out.println(" Mail sent " + mailMessage);
            mailMessage = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds wrong: wouldn't this send the **last** msg in the 5 minute window? The question here asks to **suppress** subsequent mails, after a first mail has been sent. You suppress all mails besides the last one.

Comment: `wouldn't this send the last msg in the 5 minute window?` It does. Tbh. the spec. wasn't very clear about whether to prefer old over new mails.